# Command Line print all file names in directory

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a directory that contains about 3000 images, what I would like to do is to print out (to a file if possible or even to screen) the whole images names after doing some string formatting and concatenation to them,
for example:

I would like each image name to be transformed into the following formula

```
tick.png  -->> <image src="tick.png" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Are we talking real MS-DOS or just command-line?

Comment: sorry it's Command prompt (the one that you can run it by typing 'cmd' in the run dialog), What's the difference between Command prompt and MS-DOS ?

Comment: That the command prompt is a command-line mimicking the behavior of the Operating System called MS-DOS.

Comment: CMD.EXE is a 32-bit (or 64-bit) command processor that supports MS-DOS commands. MSDOS (command.com) is 16-bit and a different beast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I suggest you to do is to write a simple [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) that processes files in the directory and outputs them in the given format.

For instance create file `run.bat` and type the following command in it:

```
FOR %%F IN (*.png) DO @echo ^<img src='%%F'/^>
```

Now, you can run the command in the command-line, by entering:

```
run
```

If you want to save the results of the batch process into a file (such as images.html), you can use:

```
run > images.html
```

If you need to add more commands/processing steps, just edit the batch file.

For a good reference on commands (such has FOR loops), see [Programming CMD](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD) on Wikibooks. Note that for complicated batch tasks, command-line interpreter may not be sufficient. For more complex batch programming, I encourage you to learn a real scripting language like Python.

Comment: Nice! I've done something better with Windows right click option on folder to create an image viewer in a html file. I love Dos batch!

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
for %f in (*.png) do echo ^<img src="%f" /^> >> myFileList.txt
```

Explanation:

```
for %f in (*.png) do <command>
```

A simple loop for all files in the current directory which match `*.png`.

```
echo ^<img src="%f" /^> >> myFileList.txt
```

Echo the string into the file (redirect output via `>>`, this will append to the file. `>` will truncate the file). `^` is need to escape the `<`.